# I am getting error in MySQL view Query,

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

```
    SELECT DISTINCT `co`.`CustomerID` AS `CustomerID`,
        `c`.`CustomerName` AS `CustomerName`,
        `c`.`CustomerAcronym` AS `CustomerAcronym`,
        `co`.`CustomerOrderID` AS `CustomerOrderID`,
        `co`.`CustomerOrderNumber` AS `CustomerOrderNumber`,
        `co`.`ProductionStatusID` AS `ProductionStatusID`,
        `ps`.`Name` AS `ProductionStatusName`,
        `sm`.`Name` AS `ShippingMethod`,
        `ois`.`TrackingNumber` AS `TrackingNumber`,
        `co`.`OrderSubmittedDate` AS `ReceivedDate`,
        `co`.`ExpectedShippingDate` AS `ExpectedShippingDate`,
        MAX(`ois`.`ShippingDate`) AS `ActualShippingDate`,
        (SELECT `CustomerOrderID` from `pt2_prod`.`orderitem` `io_one` where `io_one`.`PhotoTrackID` = "LMN_R000255346-101") as 'CustomerOrderIDOrderItem'
FROM `pt2_prod`.`customerorder` `co`
JOIN `pt2_prod`.`customer` `c` ON((`co`.`CustomerID` = `c`.`CustomerID`))
JOIN `pt2_prod`.`orderitem` `oi` ON `oi`.`CustomerOrderID` = `co`.`CustomerOrderID`
LEFT JOIN `pt2_prod`.`orderitemshipping` `ois` ON `ois`.`OrderItemID` = `oi`.`OrderItemID`
JOIN `pt2_prod`.`shippingmethod` `sm` ON `sm`.`ShippingMethodID` = `co`.`ShippingMethodID`
JOIN `pt2_prod`.`productionstatus` `ps` ON `co`.`ProductionStatusID` = `ps`.`ProductionStatusID`
where 'CustomerOrderIDOrderItem' = `co`.`CustomerOrderID`
GROUP BY `c`.`CustomerName`,
         `c`.`CustomerAcronym`,
         `co`.`CustomerOrderNumber`,
         `sm`.`Name`,
         `co`.`ExpectedShippingDate`,
         `ois`.`TrackingNumber`,
         `co`.`OrderSubmittedDate`,
         `ps`.`Name`
```

**Above is my MySQL view query. I am getting following error for the same. 
My MySQL version is 10.1.16-MariaDB in XAMPP. Please help me to resolve this error. Thank You.**

MySQL Error : #1054 - Unknown column 'CustomerOrderIDOrderItem' in 'where clause'

Comment: specify the table name so it's un-ambiguous, and also use the backticks instead of single quotes round the name, like you've done everywhere else in the query

Comment: It still won't work, because you cannot reference an alias in this way

Comment: "specify the table name so it's un-ambiguous" - For Alias ?

Comment: Then how We can reference an alias? Can anyone give me sample query?

Comment: @DeeprajParmar I guess you are searching for inner select 
`SELECT a.name FROM (SELECT name FROM agentinformation) a`  right ?

Answer (score 1):

When you have derived + aliased columns as you do, you can't use `WHERE` keyword. You have to use `HAVING` keyword.

Your query would NOT be:

```
where `CustomerOrderIDOrderItem` = `co`.`CustomerOrderID`
```

It SHOULD be:

```
HAVING `CustomerOrderIDOrderItem` = `co`.`CustomerOrderID`
```

Comment: Having clause will also not work. https://www.screencast.com/t/x1YLiBIn. Error - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY `c`.`CustomerName`,
         `c`.`CustomerAcronym`,
         `co`.`Cu' at line 21

Comment: First you use `GROUP BY`, then `HAVING`... and yes, queries with `HAVING` are usually excruciatingly slow. Rethink your logic entirely.

Comment: It's working now. I will definately rework on same query. Thank You for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise just add a `cross join`, like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `co`.`CustomerID` AS `CustomerID`,
        `c`.`CustomerName` AS `CustomerName`,
        `c`.`CustomerAcronym` AS `CustomerAcronym`,
        `co`.`CustomerOrderID` AS `CustomerOrderID`,
        `co`.`CustomerOrderNumber` AS `CustomerOrderNumber`,
        `co`.`ProductionStatusID` AS `ProductionStatusID`,
        `ps`.`Name` AS `ProductionStatusName`,
        `sm`.`Name` AS `ShippingMethod`,
        `ois`.`TrackingNumber` AS `TrackingNumber`,
        `co`.`OrderSubmittedDate` AS `ReceivedDate`,
        `co`.`ExpectedShippingDate` AS `ExpectedShippingDate`,
        MAX(`ois`.`ShippingDate`) AS `ActualShippingDate`,
        `CustomerOrderIDOrderItem`. `CustomerOrderID` AS 'CustomerOrderIDOrderItem'
FROM `pt2_prod`.`customerorder` `co`
JOIN `pt2_prod`.`customer` `c` ON((`co`.`CustomerID` = `c`.`CustomerID`))
JOIN `pt2_prod`.`orderitem` `oi` ON `oi`.`CustomerOrderID` = `co`.`CustomerOrderID`
LEFT JOIN `pt2_prod`.`orderitemshipping` `ois` ON `ois`.`OrderItemID` = `oi`.`OrderItemID`
JOIN `pt2_prod`.`shippingmethod` `sm` ON `sm`.`ShippingMethodID` = `co`.`ShippingMethodID`
JOIN `pt2_prod`.`productionstatus` `ps` ON `co`.`ProductionStatusID` = `ps`.`ProductionStatusID`
CROSS JOIN (SELECT `CustomerOrderID` from `pt2_prod`.`orderitem` `io_one` where `io_one`.`PhotoTrackID` = "LMN_R000255346-101") as CustomerOrderIDOrderItem
where `CustomerOrderIDOrderItem`.`CustomerOrderID` = `co`.`CustomerOrderID`
GROUP BY `c`.`CustomerName`,
         `c`.`CustomerAcronym`,
         `co`.`CustomerOrderNumber`,
         `sm`.`Name`,
         `co`.`ExpectedShippingDate`,
         `ois`.`TrackingNumber`,
         `co`.`OrderSubmittedDate`,
         `ps`.`Name`,
         `CustomerOrderIDOrderItem`. `CustomerOrderID`
```

Answer (score -2):

> MySQL Error : #1054 - Unknown column 'CustomerOrderIDOrderItem' in 'where clause'

try,

```
where `co`.`CustomerOrderID` = `CustomerOrderIDOrderItem`
```

instead of,

```
where  `CustomerOrderIDOrderItem` = `co`.`CustomerOrderID`
```